# How do you debug your MVC / Umbraco project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, iis, umbraco

after lot of trouble I am now able to run my Umbraco project. But there is another problem, debugging.

I can see that simple Run in debug mode will not work. I tried Attaching to porcess w3wp.exe BUT the symbols are not loaded so I can not set the break point.

Can anyone tell me how to debug MVC / Umbraco project in VS 2017 Umbraco v7 ?

Comment: Have you installed Umbraco using the nuget package? There's nothing special about debugging Umbraco

Comment: Check the build configuration, is it Debug or Release: http://prntscr.com/hg7y5v
Also, check the App pool you are attaching to for w3wp.exe - rightmost column.